# Setting child control values in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

How can I set the value of a TextBlock from a Parent Control?

i.e. my parent control (Parent.xaml) has a child control (Child.xaml) declared like this

```
<myNamespace:Child x:Name="child"/>
```

The child control contains a TextBlock declared as `<TextBlock Text="12345" x:Name="textBlock1" />`

I would like to be able to change the textbox content from Parent.xaml.cs so i tried to use

```
child.textBlock1.Text = "Some new text";
```

but i get "'Child' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'" error.

I am new to Silverlight and I'm a bit confused. Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Thanks in advance.

L

Answer (score 0):

Because `Child` is a separate control, `textBlock1` is not automatically available to the parent - it is private to the child control unless you explicitly expose it publicly.

So in the child control you could have a public property like this:

```
public string Text 
{
    set { textBlock1.Text = value; }
}
```

or you could just expose the TextBlock more directly:

```
public TextBlock ChildTextBlock 
{
    get { return textBlock1; }
}
```

There are a couple of other nicer (but slightly more complex) ways of doing it (binding, dependency properties), but these will get you started.

Comment: Thanks, the example above makes sense but the error seems to be show up when I add an x:Name to the child control inside the parent. I can't figure out why this is but I managed to solve it by using this dirty bit of code in Parent.xaml.cs:

`Child c = stackPanel.Children[0] as Child;
 c.Text = "Hello";`

Where stackPanel is the container of Child. This works after setting the property Text like in your example. Not pretty but I guess it will do for now.